# Find characters inside strings from the elements of a list in python

Tags: python-3.x

I just started to use python 3. I want to find specific characters inside a string that is part of a list. Here is my code:

```
num = ["one","two","threex"]
for item in num:
    if item.find("x"):
        print("found")
```

So, I want to print "found" if the character "x" is inside of one of the elements of the list. But when I run the code, it prints 3 times instead of one.

Why is printing 3 times? Can someone help me?

Comment: add `break` after `print("found")`

Comment: but why is printing 3 times?

Comment: From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations): the `if` interprets the following values are as false: `False, None, numeric zero of all types, and empty strings and containers (including strings, tuples, lists, dictionaries, sets and frozensets). All other values are interpreted as true.` and since [str.find](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) returns `-1` if the item is not found, it considers it `True`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find() returns -1 if the character is not found in the string. Anything that is not zero is equal to True.  try `if item.find("x") > -1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `in` again for strings:

```
num = ["one","two","threex"]
for item in num:
    if "x" in item:
        print("found")
```

Think in Strings as a list of chars like `"ext"` -> `['e', 'x', 't']`
so `"x" in "extreme"` is `True`

Answer (score 0):

You need to `break` out of `looping` through the `strings` if `'x'` is found as otherwise, it may be found in other `strings`. Also, when checking if `'x'` is in the `string`, use `in` instead.

```
num = ["one","two","threex"]
for item in num:
    if "x" in item:
        print("found")
        break
```

which `outputs`:

```
found
```

---

And if I modify the `num` `list` so that it has no `x` in any of the elements:

```
num = ["one","two","three"]
```

then there is *no* output when running the code again.

---

**But why was it `printing` `3` times before?**

Well simply, using `item.find("x")` will `return` an `integer` of the `index` of `'x'` in the `string`. And the problem with evaluating this with an `if-statement` is that an `integer` always evaluates to `True` unless it is `0`. This means that every `string` in the `num` `list` passed the test: `if item.find("x")` and so for each of the `3` `strings`, `found` was printed. In fact, the only time that `found` wouldn't be `printed` would be if the `string` began with an `'x'`. In which case, the `index` of `'x'` would be `0` and the `if` would evaluate to `False`.

Hope this clears up why your code wasn't working.

Oh, and some examples of testing the `if`:

```
>>> if 0:
...     print("yes")
... 
>>> if 1:
...     print("yes")
... 
yes
>>> if -1:
...     print("yes")
... 
yes
```

Answer (score 0):

*find returns Index if found and -1 otherwise.*

```
num = ["one","two","threex"]
for item in num:
    if item.find("x"):
        print item.find("x")
```

*i hope that you got the solution from above post ,here you know the reason why*